# How to upsample a time series using Flux (or InfluxQL if easier)?

Tags: prometheus, influxdb, promql, influxql, flux-influxdb

I have a time series with values every 5 minutes. I want to upsample it to have values every 10 seconds (the last known value is repeated) so that I can combine these values with values from another time series providing values every 10s.

How do I do that? Is that even possible? Would it be easier with PromQL in Prometheus?

In Flux, the only option I've found is the "interpolate" package :

```
  |> interpolate.linear(every: 10s)
```

It would not repeat the last known value but it would be acceptable I guess.